# ""TypeError: Cannot read property '$emit' of undefined vue

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I want to emit event from "home" component to "about" component. But it throws this exception-"TypeError: Cannot read property '$emit' of undefined".

This is my "main.js"

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";

export const bus = new Vue();
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  router,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

This is my "Home" component.

```html
<template>
  <div class="home">
    <input
      v-model="text"
      class="text-input"
      placeholder="Add text to your child component"
    />
    <button @click="sendmsg" class="btn-add">Add message</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { bus } from "../main";

export default {
  name: "home",
  data() {
    return {
      text: "",
    };
  },
  methods: {
    sendmsg() {
      bus.$emit("msg", this.text);
      this.text = "";
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

And this "About" component

```html
<template>
  <div class="about"></div>
</template>

<script>
import { bus } from "../main";
export default {
  name: "about",
  created() {
    bus.$on("message", (data) => {
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a race-condition brought on by a possible circular dependency (*main* -> *App* -> *Home* -> *main*).

I would suggest moving your `bus` to its own module instead of `main`. See [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/vuejs-global-event-bus) for an example

```js
// src/event-bus.js
import Vue from 'vue'
export default new Vue()
```

and then in `Home.vue` and `About.vue`

```js
import bus from '@/event-bus'
```

Also, your `About` component is listening for the wrong event. `Home` emits *"msg"* but `About` listens for *"message"*. They should use the same event name.

Demo ~ https://codesandbox.io/s/serverless-frog-kvtoj?file=/src/event-bus.js

Comment: [Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property '$emit' of undefined"found in

---> <Home> at src/views/Home.vue
       <App> at src/App.vue
         <Root>                                                                                                 
         TypeError: Cannot read property '$emit' of undefined

Comment: @DimitarIvanov works fine for me. I added a CodeSandbox demo to my answer

Comment: @DimitarIvanov try following the tutorial and Phil's example. I also re-created the same code and it works just fine.

Comment: @JakubASuplicki I too had a funny feeling OP's code _should_ work but I find it best to avoid circular dependencies wherever possible anyway

Comment: @Phil I agree, that is definitely something worth pointing out. They are pretty difficult to test as well. I believe that in the end, it makes the application harder to maintain. Personally, I was concerned about the file structure at first but then he seems to be following the baseline so there should not be an issue with that.

Answer (score 0):

It's working, but whem the components have their own view it's stop working.

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="app">
    <router-link to="/"> HOME</router-link>
    <router-link to="/about"> About</router-link>
    <router-view />
  </div>
</template>

<style lang="scss">
.app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  align-items: center;
  .btn-add {
    width: 10vw;
  }
  .text-input {
    width: 10vw;
  }
}
</style>
```

index.js

```
import Vue from "vue";
import VueRouter from "vue-router";
import Home from "../views/Home.vue";

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "Home",
    component: Home
  },
  {
    path: "/about",
    name: "About",
    // route level code-splitting
    // this generates a separate chunk (about.[hash].js) for this route
    // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
    component: () =>
      import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ "../views/About.vue")
  }
];

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: "history",
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes
});

export default router;
```